# "df -h" and "zfs list" more than 2 TB difference

Tags: disk-usage, zfs

**Output of df -h:**

[image]

**Output of sudo zfs list:**

[image]

It is about the directory /storage/dockervolumes/nextcloud. As you can see the difference between the outputs is huge. When I actually go to the directory nextcloud and type *sudo du -sh .* the output is only 1.1 G which means that only 1 G is being used. Where are all the other 2500G gone?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If possible, please avoid attaching screenshots of console output, it is often hard to read and usually requires copy-typing if a contributor wants to reproduce what happened. Instead, copy and paste it to include it in your question, with proper formatting as code.

Comment: You are using snapshots, so have a look at them with `zfs list -t snapshot`